# Photoshop rectangle properties do not show up

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I create a rectangle in Photoshop when i hit properties it does not show object properties for some reason. only mask properties. any idea why that might be and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there's two options on top of the Properties window (right under the title)

1. Live Shape Properties
2. Masks

make sure you click on the "Live Shape Properties" symbol

[image: Properties window - Live Shape Properties]